# Function call with additional custom arguments

Tags: r, function, ellipsis

I'm trying to wrap my head around ellipsis in R. I have a function and want to be able to pass additional arguments to the function as needed, for example whether or not to return a df or similar. Can I not specify variable names? This is a very simplified example and I want to be able to make this optional to keep function calls as easy and clean as possible with multiple possible conditionals within the function for various scenarios.

```
 custom.fun<-function(x, y, z, ...){

 a<-sum(x, y, z)

   if (exists('return.var') && return.var=='yes'){
     return(a)
   }
 }

 A<-custom.fun(1,2,3,return.var='yes')
```

This returns Null, as it is obviously not passing on return.var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do something similar to this, capture all the optional argument in `list` and check if `any` of them have the required name and value.

```
custom.fun<-function(x, y, z, ...){
   opt_args <- list(...)
   a <- sum(x, y, z)
   if (any(names(opt_args) == 'return.var' & opt_args == 'yes'))
       return(a)
   else 
       return('No arg')
}

custom.fun(1,2,3,return.var = 'yes')
#[1] 6

custom.fun(1,2,3,var = 'yes')
#[1] "No arg"

custom.fun(1,2,3,var='no', return.var = 'yes')
#[1] 6
```

Comment: Ok, almost perfect. In my understanding, this should work with any string, not just 'yes', but as soon as I change it to anything else, it stops working and the conditional returns FALSE. Like I  literally change only the two "yes" to "true" or "y", for example, and it doesn't match it in any()

Comment: @Anke It works for me if I change the last part in `if` line to `opt_args == 'true'` and call it by `custom.fun(1,2,3,var='no', return.var = 'true')` Did you run the function again after changing it?

Comment: Found my mistake, so sorry. Instead of opt_args=='yes' I had return.var=='yes' and it was working because I guess I had previously defined return.var as "yes" and didn't clear my variables. Thanks again foryour help!

Comment: It can actually be even shorter and less convoluted as: if(opt_args$return.var=='yes')){ return(a)}